# how to handle unexpected error and uncaught exceptions

Tags: android

I use "try catch" to handle some expected error，
but sometime, there will be unexpected error.

i mean if i don't use "try catch" , how to handle crash error ,and send error message to server?

I have try   "UncaughtExceptionHandler" , 
but it will block app.

thank in advance

Comment: You could `catch (Excepction ex)`

Answer (score 0):

A try catch will also be able to catch unexpected errors. You just have to put them in the appropriate order: the most specific first, then more general. An example (it's general Java, no specific Android code, but you'll get the point):

```
    try {
        int input = sc.nextInt();  //random number
        int amount = 10 / input;   // not every result can be stored in an int
    } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
        // catches error of non-numeric value
        System.out.println("input is not a valid number");
    } catch (ArithmeticException ae) {
        //catches error of division by 0
        System.out.println("Division by 0!");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // catches any other error
        System.out.println("other error");
    }
```