# Android: Is it possible that LVL3 methods crash of their own?

Tags: android, crash, google-play-services, in-app-billing, android-lvl

My app checks for licensing by means of the Google library LVL3.

The above mentioned verification is made of several steps and every possible exception and error is handled. The app functionality depends on the result of the check so if it fails the app doesn't work. With "fail" I mean a real crash.

I would like to avoid that the app is crashed, so I am asking here if it is anyhow possible that some method of the library can crash of its own, thus impairing the app.

Comment: You can find some crash reports in this [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=google+library+crash&colspec=ID+Status+Priority+Owner+Summary+Stars+Reporter+Opened&cells=tiles). If you'd like also to get the crash reports, you can use [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra). It is a library enabling Android Application to automatically post their crash reports to a GoogleDoc form. It is targetted to android applications developers to help them get data from their applications when they crash or behave erroneously.

Comment: Also, we can't be certain for the unexpected errors since its a google proprietary product. What I can suggest is for you to handle expected exceptions. Not catching Exception since its an antipattern. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761897/how-to-handle-unexpected-error-and-uncaught-exceptions) might help.